# TS generic eventHandler with match function

Tags: typescript, types

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgIzIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIDkGWY2tRJcA5taQK7kBG0AgF8CBUJFiIUDcACZ8rYmUo1aAOQgAPMLJYlkAGzgBnMGopdTUUO2GiwATwAOKAKohgAexAywyALxomDjIAD5BjLKiYuDQ8EgR4AAScCAAJgbQADwAKshakOnGyO5ePsFgAHwKxORwYAgAFtA0ABQgnmlcpd6+AJQB1R1dyMDFqNpQiGBZPeWMADTIOZUA3KyNqRktyO2dXDkD-tXonsBp6yII3qaGY4XQxjS+KemZULMevRWVANoAugFkAD1gQtE5PFA-NcQLc4Gk0i8tu8gbl8tosGlinNfJVWhtkTskW9sisCEdqoRiAZ7lhHgA6JzcYyNVqbElQPrrfQ83k8gD0-OQAD1kABBKDsXiMZCeGDIRwuOjE7YfFa0UbFDp+EzGYDsMh8TIKzzIJxwKaUCSy+WKlD0CqvVWfMq42j05DCUEEQXIZkQUTwxGOwlQVpUkh1BrNMMQCp9GhxmVjNCTaYu76LfDKLjqAq6ISVRQ1PlQCBgbhQEAKqDcAP6IQLYvs1WtJNyAYR3kw4yeTL0gyedhtiqyek5vrFkRCPpAA)

Which TS rule I broke? How can I rewrite?

```ts
interface Event1 {
    name: 'Event1'
    age: number
}

interface Event2 {
    name: 'Next2'
    lastName: string
}

type UnionEvent = Event1 | Event2


interface EventHandler<T extends UnionEvent> {
  matcher: (node: UnionEvent) => node is Extract<UnionEvent, T>;
  handler: (node: T) => void;
}
const listeners: EventHandler<UnionEvent>[] = [];

export const addEventHandler = <T extends UnionEvent>(
  handler: EventHandler<T>
) => {
  listeners.push(handler);
                    // ^ Argument of type 'EventHandler<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventHandler<UnionEvent>'. 
};
```

Next variant with `any`, but it is not look as solution

[Ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgIzIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIDkGWY2tRJcA5taQK7kBG0AgF8CBUJFiIUDcACZ8rYmUo1aAOQgAPMLJYlkAGzgBnMGopdTUUO2GiwATwAOKAKohgAexAywyALxomDjIAD5BjLKi+jGxcfEJMQD0SchwIA5i4NDwSBHgABLpACYG0AA8ACrIWpAgxcbI7l4+wX6B6Q4AfArE5HBgCAAW0DQAFCCexVzN3r4AlAE9k9PIwI2o2lCIYOWzrYwANMiVXQDcrEMlZVDjK1yVi-496J7AxRciBClpUNsOyE8MDSGWQgF4NwByOwQEN5TIZ1nVoMYaL4ivUbgBtAC6AWQ2IuBC0Tk8UD8MJAcLgxWKqOu0FxVRq2iwDSaHjmbS6Y0udNu+TAaNKFVOBCePUIxAMCKwSIAdE5uMYhmMrujoPNPgSfoqIKIqTS2oKbmMJSR+oMRlAxhA2vMaDbGGsNlsdnt2QdwMc8MouOparohF1FL04lAIGBuFAQMgwFBuLr9EJDsHVUKrQ65ItTbFycZPGVZQZPOxrW1ZLKffNgyIhPMgA)

```ts
                                            // any
interface EventHandler<T extends UnionEvent = any> {
  matcher: (node: UnionEvent) => node is Extract<UnionEvent, T>;
  handler: (node: T) => void;
}

// array of any 
const listeners: EventHandler[] = [];

export const addEventHandler = <T extends UnionEvent>(
  handler: EventHandler<T>
) => {
  listeners.push(handler);
};
```

I tried to use inherit from base event class

```ts
  interface BaseEvent {
    name: string
  }

interface Event1 extends BaseEvent {
    name: 'Event1'
    age: number
}

interface Event2 extends BaseEvent {
    name: 'Next2'
    lastName: string
}

interface EventHandler<T extends BaseEvent> {
  matcher: (node: UnionEvent) => node is Extract<UnionEvent, T>;
  handler: (node: T) => void;
}
const listeners: EventHandler<BaseEvent>[] = [];

export const addEventHandler = <T extends BaseEvent>(
  handler: EventHandler<T>
) => {
  listeners.push(handler);
                    // ^ Argument of type 'EventHandler<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventHandler<UnionEvent>'. 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire error message looks like:

```
Argument of type 'EventHandler<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventHandler<UnionEvent>'.
  Types of property 'handler' are incompatible.
    Type '(node: T) => void' is not assignable to type '(node: UnionEvent) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'node' and 'node' are incompatible.
        Type 'UnionEvent' is not assignable to type 'T'.
          'UnionEvent' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'UnionEvent'.
            Type 'Event1' is not assignable to type 'T'.
              'Event1' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'UnionEvent'.(2345)
```

The last line is important:
`'Event1' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'UnionEvent'.`

To understand this message, it is helpful to think about subtypes in terms of sets - all values of the subtype belong to supertype.

I can easily find 2 subtypes of UnionEvent - Event1 and Event2.

In your example, you passed an event handler:

```
addEventHandler({
    matcher(event): event is Extract<UnionEvent, {name: 'Next2'}>
    {
        return true
    },
    handler(event2) {
        console.log(event2.name)
    }
})
```

which is an `EventHandler<Event2>`
and you are trying to store in a list of `EventHandler<Event1 | Event2>`

The compiler objects, and rightfully so - imagine the following code:

```ts
listeners.forEach(listener => listener.handler({name: 'Event1', age: 1}));
```

You stored an object with a function which can only handle `Event2`, but `Event1` happened, and this causes a runtime error.
To prevent it, the compiler prevents the store.

Now, you have the extra knowledge that the call to `handler` will be preceded by a call to `match`, and `handler` will only be called when the type is correct.

You can pass this knowledge to compiler:

```ts
type EventHandlerWithTypeTest = (node: UnionEvent) => void;

const makeHandlerWithTypeTest = <T extends UnionEvent>(handler: EventHandler<T>) => {
  return (node: UnionEvent): void => {
    if (handler.matcher(node)) {
      handler.handler(node);
    }
  }
}

const listeners: EventHandlerWithTypeTest[] = [];

const addEventHandler = <T extends UnionEvent>(
  handler: EventHandler<T>
) => {
  listeners.push(makeHandlerWithTypeTest(handler));
};
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6&ssl=35&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgIzIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIDkGWY2tRJcA5taQK7kBG0AgF8CBUJFiIUDcACZ8rYmUo16mOSxLIANnADOYAHIUuBqKHbDRYAJ4AHFAFUQwAPYgZYZAF406psgAPn6MsqLi0PBIIeAAEnAgACba0AA8ACrIEAAekEl6yM5uHv4AfArE5HBgCAAW0DQAFCCuiVxF7p4AlD7lLW3IwAWouVCIYKkdJYwANMjppQDcrLUJyQ3Iza1c6T3e5eiuwInLIgS2DjFg8UkpUADqwGC16fYQ6RAGPpv97S6d-j2ByOJ1ECHcXyqAGsIDd1g8ni83h8vr4MllclhEgUpp5So1VrcNp44XcMqUgRVkFAIGBuFAQD9tjRcYCaIdjr0qcRgDBNoT4QA6Ko1epQLZtLo9QhaYgCu6C%20XQCUQLrLLQiYgiM7gkBfbRDPLQPQ0ElrO6PZ6vBwosAAbQAut9HcsCLqvnBEokzUSoN90Tk8tjCv9puB8StzcT-KS0gsCJSZTpDVhjYK7Nw9LVGtDYVGEVbkZ8wAT81LTq6CAB6KvITMQAie70x-ONJOVap1ZUQNlZfyDYajcaTUOeOZ4ZRcNShWhCUqKbmyml0hl9xiCyc%20by%20acaBdCGYLpXinuhaULrTu1wpQXaVzsRq0ACCL9oc1Pcg3Jnf-lkt-0RgmF0%207CMBBAGgYqZQHogowK4UCoIg2YQUafr7MmkEgMqE4mKonjMHMHBcNgQjluBKZYdBsHwYhdSNChUFcgxlFtpOeG-m%20OgAcYKh0MwpFqkAA)

Comment: Yes, thanks is it works. It is exactly what I want. But I still don't get how makeHandlerWithTypeTest keeps type...

Comment: Ok, I got it. ` listeners.push(handler)` from my example does know nothing about how code will be executed. @Lesiak 

Answer (score 1):

In passing in `UnionEvent` to `EventHandler`, you are effectively specifying an object of the following shape

```
EventHandler<UnionEvent>

{
  matcher: (node: UnionEvent) => node is UnionEvent;
  handler: (node: UnionEvent) => void;
}
```

this is not compatible with something like

```
EventHandler<Event1>

{
  matcher: (node: UnionEvent) => node is Event1;
  handler: (node: Event1) => void;
}
```

as in the former example we are mandating that `handler` is a function that accepts a `node` that is capable of being both `Event1` or `Event2`. In the latter example `node` can only be `Event1` which is incompatible.

Consider this simplified example

```
type StringOrNumberFunction = (stringOrNumber: string | number) => void

function stringFn(str: string) {}
function numberFn(num: number) {}
function stringOrNumberFn(strOrNum: string | number) {}

const assignedFunction: StringOrNumberFunction = stringFn          // invalid
const assignedFunction: StringOrNumberFunction = numberFn          // invalid
const assignedFunction: StringOrNumberFunction = stringOrNumberFn  // valid
```

Only `stringOrNumberFn` can be assigned because the function needs to be capable of accepting both `string` or `number`

---

What I think you are after instead is

```
type UnionEventHandler = EventHandler<Event1> | EventHandler<Event2>
```

```
interface EventHandler<T extends UnionEvent> {
  matcher: (node: UnionEvent) => node is T
  handler: (node: T) => void;
}

const listeners: UnionEventHandler[] = [];
const addEventHandler = (eventHandler: UnionEventHandler) => {
  listeners.push(eventHandler);    // valid
};

// use

declare const event1Matcher: EventHandler<Event1>['matcher'] // (node: UnionEvent) => node is Event1
declare const event1Handler: EventHandler<Event1>['handler'] // (node: Event1) => void
declare const event2Matcher: EventHandler<Event2>['matcher'] // (node: UnionEvent) => node is Event2
declare const event2Handler: EventHandler<Event2>['handler'] // (node: Event2) => void

addEventHandler({ matcher: event1Matcher, handler: event1Handler })    // valid
addEventHandler({ matcher: event2Matcher, handler: event2Handler })    // valid
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is also works. I do not want to define additional types like `declare const event1Matcher: EventHandler<Event1>['matcher'] // (node: UnionEvent) => node is Event1`. Ts playground from green answer shows how it works without additional types.